# Equal Height images in Flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is easier to show in an image- http://puu.sh/n8WGw/0b01b020c7.png

I want the flex container to shrink as it's doing now, to match the height of the largest image, but I want the other images to match the height of the flex container. Whenever I try, they just become full height (their original height). Is there a way to accomplish this?

If I've not explained it well enough - I want the images to take up 100% of their li parent height, as shown by the blue box in the image attached.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you care about distortion of the images...or overflow?

Comment: They should be stretched vertically to match the height of the tallest image (which would have correct aspect ratio)- width-wise, they need to be identical.

Comment: have you tried to give height: 100% and bottom:0 to the images?

Comment: So like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KVEqrM It stretches the short image to the right height....but you will get some distortion.

Comment: You can't do that at all without script, and even with, it will get messy, so what is most important, aspect ratio, full height, ...?

Comment: @Paulie_D It would need to scale down with the page width, but we're ditching the idea anyway. Thanks all

Comment: If you check the Codepen is *does* scale down with viewport size.

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what you did really, maybe overused flexbox rules ?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
img {
  height: 100%;/* in flex-child, the tallest will set rythm ... here it's about 200px; + gap height underneath if no reset of display or vertical-align */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/100/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/150/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/100/" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

or if flex set on li

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* img will be cut off */
}
img {
  min-height: 100%;/* again , tallest should set the rythm */
  min-width: 100%; /* unless one doesn't fit the width */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/100/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/150/" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/50/" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```